# JAVA DOM: duplicated attributes

Tags: java, dom, attributes, html-parsing

I'm using the DOM library for JAVA and some entries XHTML encounter this problem:

[Fatal Error] tree.xml:238:185: Attribute "itemprop" was already specified for element "span".

This is the XHTML part with problems:

```
<span class='fn' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person' itemprop='name'>Rodrigo</span>
```

Exists some option to allow duplicate attributes in DOM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the [Microdata specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#microdata) only allows one itemprop per HTML element, meaning that the DOM library you're using is properly marking it as invalid markup.  If you want to specify multiple values, they need to be space-separated, like this:

```
<span class='fn' itemprop='author name' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>Rodrigo</span>
```

Incidentally, the class attribute works the same way.

Comment: Yes, I know it. This HTML is downloaded from a webpage which I don't have control. Exists some option to allow this in DOM or to resolve duplicated attributes?